# need to get callback of new sforce.SObject ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax-toolkit

im creating SObject("Attachment") the problem is depends on how big is the file usually it take some amount of seconds do get the results. I want to find a away to alert me when the result comes back so i can stop the spinner.

```
<script src="/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script> 
    var AttachmentList = [];
    var att = new sforce.SObject("Attachment");
    att.Name = this.file.name;
    att.ContentType = this.file.type;
    att.Body = (new sforce.Base64Binary(e.target.result)).toString();
    AttachmentList.push(att);
    var attachmentListJSON = JSON.stringify(AttachmentList);
    console.log('attachmentListJSON');
    console.log(attachmentListJSON);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you can use asynchronous methods in [AJAX Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples_asynch.htm) which provide you with a callback whenever the result is returned:

Example:

```
var account = new sforce.SObject("Account");
account.Name = "my new account";

sforce.connection.create([account], {
  onSuccess: function(result) {
    if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
      spinner(hide);
    } else {
      showError();
    }
  },
  onFailure: function(error) {
    showError();
  }
});
```

Comment: It's the `AJAX Toolkit`. Calling it `connection js` is a bit off the mark. You should also declare your `function` variables as `const` so they are locally scoped. Or just make them anonymous as part of your parameters.